# want some extra space while scroll list to bottom so that floatingactionbutton does not overview on list last item?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-layout

I have a list.generate and a floating action button,

here my list showing all transactions , but facing a problem that when I scroll down to last transaction, I can't see right side of transaction as floating action button coming on transaction card

**so I want a more some space only while I reach at bottom of list..**

here is my simple code

```
class ShowTransactionWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Transaction> mylist;

  ShowTransactionWidget({required this.mylist});

  //Todo add little bit more space while scrolling


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
          child: Column(
            children: List.generate(mylist.length, (index) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  TransactionCard(transaction: mylist[index],),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 8.0),
                    child: Divider(
                      thickness: 0.9,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
            }),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

}
```

I have attached an image regarding it[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another widget on Column based on last index like

```dart
children: List.generate(mylist.length, (index) {
  return Column(
    children: [
      .....
      if (index == mylist.length - 1)
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
    ],
  );
}),
```

Based on your UI. I will prefer using `ListView.separated` and ListView provides `padding`.

Comment: As you pointed out, `ListView` has `padding` property; setting a bottom padding is often a better approach.